# What is the best way to ask a theoretical question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Recently I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666726/css-layout-not-working-on-load-but-fine-after-that), that was immediately put on hold.  The reason was because the question could not be verified as I was unable **for security and business reasons** to put the code online.

Suffice to say, I was a little upset given that I acknowledged my shortcomings in the question, and because none of the close voters responded to my queries of how I could improve the question.  Indeed, the one person who did answer provided me with enough information to troubleshoot and solve the problem.

I'm over it, but I'm still a bit perplexed. So much of what we do with computers is theoretical.  Is there a way to ask such questions without them being put on hold for narrow non-compliance?

Comment: It was put on hold by _five_ users. Any question requires five votes  to put on hold. (Or one vote by an actual (diamond next to name) moderator.)

Comment: Did you delete the question? Could you reproduce the text or a screenshot here?

Comment: Right there in my last sentence, "I know y'all are going to want to see the question..."  And so here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666726/css-layout-not-working-on-load-but-fine-after-that

Comment: The fact that a question is theoretically in no way necessarily precludes it from being appropriate.  Many theoretical questions also happen to be very broad, instead of very specific theoretical questions, or are vague and unclear, or are off topic, or are subjective.  Practical questions can have all of those same problems too.

Comment: I should clarify...the question itself was not theoretical as much as it asked for any hypotheses that might solve a problem.  Thanks Josh for pointing that out.

Comment: Actually, one part of this question I wanted answered but didn't press...what is the obligation of reviewers who put a question on hold?  I got little response to repeated questioning and question re-writes did not seem to be revisited.  Is it "fair" to put a question on hold and then that's that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would not use the word "theoretical" here except in the colloquial sense meaning "non-concrete", which is what caused the closure. Yes, you've acknowledged the obstacles to providing more information, but the fact remains that the question does not seem to be answerable except with more information, and that's exactly why we close questions -- because they're not going to lead to a specific, substantial, factual, helpful-to-future-searchers answer.

This one, unfortunately, looks like it leads straight to an interactive debugging session, and that's not something that Stack Overflow is meant to facilitate. Look at it from our point of view: if you're not sure where the problem is, and can't show us the stuff that's causing it, how are we supposed to have any idea at all what it is? You need to find some way to produce a more tangible demonstration of the problem, preferably by creating a [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Another possible direction for editing would be to ask for specific debugging steps you can take to investigate the nature of the problem. I'd still suggest being more detailed in your question: get into the nitty-gritty technical detail of your debugging so far, and ask for the very next moves you should make based on that information. That would still produce the kind of answer that Stack Overflow seeks.

Comment: Now regretting my use of the word "theoretical," but with all due respect I just don't think it's at issue here.  I'm clear on the concept of asking meaningful questions and I'm not sure how I could have provided the code sample.  This question was "what can I try to solve this problem?"  So along the lines of what Servy says, above, is the problem with the limitations the question puts on the answers?

Comment: I don't read solicitation of answers to "what steps can I take to debug this situation" in your question right now, @DaveKaye, but I think that would indeed be an acceptable post. If you are still interested in getting it reopened, I'd definitely suggest editing in that direction. Get into as much nitty-gritty technical detail as you can about the debugging you've already done, and ask what the very next steps should be. (Also, while you're at it, please [leave out the salutations and "thanks"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/).)

Comment: I appreciate it but I got the question answered.  That's why I'm here asking.  The one person who read through what I was saying gave me a hint that lead to the solution.  I'm not looking for a "do-over," really just trying to understand 1) What went wrong and 2) how to avoid this mistake in the future.

Comment: Sure; I hope that you find this applies to future questions as well.

Comment: Do have to point out, my question did include what had been tried and what I thought were potential next steps.  Was that information not specific enough?

Comment: I see the information there, @DaveKaye, and I admit that I don't have any domain knowledge, so I _definitely_ may be wrong, but no, it doesn't look detailed enough to me. Of course, it's hard to find the balance between "dump **all the info** so everything's completely explicit" and "explain the overview because I'm dealing with intelligent humans".

Comment: Learned that one the hard way today.

Answer (score 5):

Your question was closed, "because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem."

Theoretical questions are fine, so long as enough information is included for them to be answered.  This doesn't necessarily mean providing all of the code, but in practice, providing sufficient information for questions on SO often requires posting *some* code (even if it's an example, and not the code you are using in your application, so long as it also replicates the problem).  If you can manage to provide enough information for the question to be answerable without any code, then that's fine.  According to the 5 people that votes to close your question, you did not succeed in your attempts.

Comment: In this case there was too much code to post.  The fact that the code was pulled from various legacy systems kept me from being able to narrow it down to any one thing I could turn around and post.  The one reply that suggested I disable JavaScript lead me to the eventual answer, which to me suggests that there was enough information, no?

Comment: @DaveKaye And while it was able to lead you to an answer, there wasn't enough information in the post for anyone *else* to answer the question.  The fact that *only you* could answer it is what conclusively tells us that your question was lacking in information.  If you have too much code, work on trimming it down to a minimal reproducible example.  See [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) for help with that.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to ask a question about a "hypothetical situation" (which, to be honest, was just a situation in your code you didn't feel like fully disclosing) is to recreate as small an example as possible of that situation which reproduces either the jumping off place, or the hypothetical situation so that users can post an answer.

For example, you do not need to show every line of code on the page in order to demonstrate a hover affect for a menu item. All you need to show is the menu item, and the relevant hover affect.

Comment: Again, that just wasn't possible.  In addition to the problem being caused by code being pulled from multiple legacy sources I didn't fully have access to I wasn't completely sure what the problem even was and so couldn't have isolated it if I wanted to.

Comment: Look at it from our point of view, @DaveKaye: if you're not completely sure what the problem is, how are we supposed to have any idea at all? On the other hand, if you want specific steps you can take to investigate the nature of the problem, that's another thing which _should_ work out as a question. That's not (as I said in a comment on my answer) really coming across right now.

Comment: Josh, I think that is a very useful response...

Comment: With the benefit of long hindsight @jscs : sometimes figuring out the problem is as useful or more useful than figuring the answer.  So the 2nd part of this I can agree with if maybe not the first.