# Meta-meta: why is meta full of close-warriors?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, meta, deleted-questions

Every time I see meta questions coming up in the Community Bulletin link on the side of SO, nearly all the questions are "close-warrior" topics (i.e. aimed at removal of content deemed bad to the person posting the question rather than the creation of useful content or the improvement of naturally-arising low-quality content). Why is this?

Are these just the questions that get attention? And is it wrong for SO to be drawing more attention to them via the Community Bulletin links?

As a high-rep user who both asks and answers lots of questions, I find this sort of "deletion culture" unpleasant and counter-productive. I don't think I've ever seen a case where an inappropriate question stuck around for more than a few hours, much less days, and I've seen plenty of low-quality but valid questions closed or even deleted. So the interest in expanding closure/deletion seems like it's more in the interest of people who spend their time voting to close and delete and less in the interest of people who ask and answer questions.

Comment: Remember that the CB links are *autogenerated* from active posts. The controversial ones are naturally more active.

Comment: Yeah I figured that may be part of it (see the second paragraph of my question) but I believe there's still an interesting question here (see the second sentence of the second paragraph, etc.).

Comment: Are you saying we are closing and deleting too much? Have any more concrete examples, your post is somewhat vague. There are a lot of discussions about the quality levels of new questions and how to best handle these; there is a sentiment that quality has dropped. You may want to listen to the podcast currently linked in the CB.

Comment: +1 Anything closed that is linked from meta gets deleted. Rather unfortunate.

Comment: @user000001: Yes, the abuse of deletion is really ridiculous. It does not add anything of value to the site or the internet; it only subtracts (admittedly often minuscule, but sometimes not) value. But fixing that problem is a separate question from mine, I think.

Comment: "It does not add anything of value to the site" - yes it does, deleting misinformation is important, and there are a lot of bad/old questions that contain dangerous misinformation about technologies. Especially in certain tags.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Closing, maybe not too much, but definitely sufficiently. Deleting, definitely way too much, but that's not actually what I'm saying here. This question is about the *culture* of closing/deletion on meta.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: My point in this question is not to argue about specifics of deletion, but there are plenty of ways (e.g. editing) to mark information as outdated or potentially-outdated without deleting it. Even better, you can do something constructive and provide updated information.

Comment: @R.. as for the question - true, I upvoted the question, I think the negativity some people bring and the fact some people are obsessive on closing/deleting rather than being more helpful is both dangerous and counter productive. That said, policing SO is how we keep a high quality site. Back to the topic! I was commenting on your previous comment: Very often, in questions like "Framework A vs. Framework B" there is really nothing good to add, they often contain a lot of misinformation and opinions and they are just a subjective popularity contest most of the time.

Comment: Don't you mean close worriers :-)?

Comment: “Deletion culture.” Dear goodness.

Comment: It is a hot topic right now, been so since SO got its own meta.  You probably never paid attention to meta before until it started showing up on your front page.  Nothing whatsoever to do with "culture" of course.

Comment: "it's more in the interest of people who spend their time voting to close and delete and less in the interest of people who ask and answer questions" .. amen, exactly, this, etc. basically close warriors need to get a life.

Comment: @necro You will not find very many people who are willing to answer your question if the site is unmoderated. It boggles my mind how many people come to Stack Overflow and complain that it isn't like all those other sites they are *not* asking their questions on.

Comment: @CodyGray this site became successful well before the horde of close warriors descended upon it. the voting and reputation system has and continues to be good enough. do you really think questions with 5 downvotes will not be distinguished from a question with an upvote? why do we rarely see 5 downvotes but see so many questions closed within minutes of being asked even as people are answering them? the answer lies in some deep psychological corner of closers. other than by downvoting, why get in the way of people willing to answer questions that others have asked? sigh, you got me started!

Comment: We don't see 5 downvotes because most people think close voting is enough. People are afraid to "double-up" on the "punishment" of doing both. Because closing serves a more visible and immediate purpose than downvoting, people tend to prefer doing that. And yes, @necromancer, the site became successful before close voting. It was also a lot smaller and had a rather different audience. Most of the early participants were regular readers of Jeff Atwood's personal blog on programming.

Comment: @necromancer I suggest you study the help section. You seem to have misconceptions about "closing". Closing is not "killing a question". Please research.

Comment: "I don't think I've ever seen a case where an inappropriate question stuck around for more than a few hours, much less days"  Are you active in many low-traffic tags?  I've had to flag some questions for moderation attention because of low views and a lack of users with the ability to close-vote.  E.g., (haven't flagged this one, but it's an example) [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23930528/1281433) where even one of the developers of the library at hand (AndyS) agrees it's a duplicate, but after 4 days, it's got only 17 views and only 3 close votes.

Comment: @kapa: I suggest you look at the real world. When people ask a question and it gets closed, they perceive it as "my question was killed". Sometimes, it pays to look at the real world *outside* the help section.

Comment: Or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23883943/1281433) that's got a score of -2, two close votes, but only 14 views after 6 days.  Bad questions can stick around for quite some time in low-traffic tags.  I was happy to hear about the "gold tag single vote close vote" except for the fact that low-traffic tags often don't have even one gold-tag user, even though the *top user* can confidently say "this is a duplicate of the question asked 6 months ago, and I know because I answered that one, too."

Comment: @false do you have a problem with the term? It's not the first time it crops up, and it probably won't be the last. And the term exists because it is obviously appropriate. If you find this hard to swallow, do ask some of the more senior moderators about the *last* big close/delete war. And maybe try, just *try* to pretend to keep your comments sounding respectful, or at least, non-dismissive, when you've got that friggin' diamond next to your name. Thank you. I don't want to see the same uproar again that we had the last time meta convinced itself that everything must go.

Comment: @jalf It's their problem. Their question is not killed, just taken to hospital, and they are responsible for healing it. Honestly, we do not need them here if they are not capable of understanding simple rules. This is not a charity site, and not a site where we look after people's nice little feelings. This is a site for programmers.

Comment: I'm really happy we now have the "Community Bulletin" on Stack Overflow because I feel it brings more users like you to the Meta site. In the past, Meta has already had it's own subculture that I do not think represents the majority of Stack Overflow users, and the majority of them favor closure/deletion of content. Now I am seeing a much more diverse set of opinions coming to meta from regular users like yourself, and an happy to see many fresh voices on meta. Please keep raising points that concern you, and voice your opinion in cases where you disagree. :)

Comment: @necromancer, speaking as someone who's been here a long time and only recently became a "close warrior" -- my impression is that we're dealing with a large influx of people who don't understand the goals of the site (to build a canonical repository of high-quality questions and answers useful to others). Closing things not in line with that goal, and communicating to people *why* those questions needed to be closed (and how to improve them) is part of how we try to preserve that culture, and guide the new folks coming in towards making a more positive contribution towards that original goal.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: do low traffic tags behave like popular tags, but in slow motion? If that question with 14 views and 2 close votes gets closed on (approximately) its 35th view then although R.. is mistaken to say that it doesn't take much *time* to close bad questions under the existing processes, he may still be right in substance to claim that closing already happens in due course with little fuss.

Comment: @SteveJessop Some things get closed without too much problem, just in a longer amount of time.  Some things tend to stay open for a long time, even if they're pretty clear cases.  E.g,. [from OWL to Prolog code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250620/from-owl-to-prolog-code), which is two months old, has 68 views, is a pretty clear library/tool request, and has only one close vote.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I believe your comment exemplifies what the OP is trying to point out. I do not read that question strictly as a tool recommendation. The user is saying, "I have this problem. I looked at this tool, but I couldn't figure it out." Now, that might be closeable as too broad or lacks sufficient information, but it also may be *salvageable*. We cannot afford to be haphazard or sloppy if we're going to push for the removal/closing of content; if we are not careful, we're going to make matters worse, not better. I believe this is the concern the OP is trying to raise.

Comment: It happened to me and I got no explanation from the closers or from SO -- frustrating!  I finally opened a meta-question (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250186/what-is-the-best-way-to-ask-a-theoretical-question) to get an answer which was also frustrating because the responders insisted on giving an "obvious" answer despite my repeated explanations as to why asking the question in a certain way just wasn't possible.  Closing is great, closing is useful, but the closers have a responsibility to explain themselves.  Otherwise they're just like cops who write tickets for no good reason.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't see why simple search technology cannot sift the good (upvoted) from the "bad" (downvoted) and diminish the presentation of the latter except to those specifically interested in it? Or simply tag it as "wish-this-were-not-here" or "wish-this-were-unanswered" in lieu of close. The problem lies deeper in the psyche, perhaps subconscious, of close warriors. It smells like power-tripping but of course nobody can prove that and most will not admit it.

Comment: @DaveKaye usually opening a meta-question will add insult to injury, and that's what this question is about -- why is meta so full of people like that when the rest of the community chugs along fine?

Comment: @necromancer: Exactly.

Comment: Imagine if all this effort were put into creating good content, reviewing upvoting good questions/answers.  The mechanics will bring the good answers to the top, and then readers will see that before they see the bad content.  There's millions of terrible webpages out there, but it doesn't stop the good ones that get good rankings from being successful and reaching readers.  Same applies to questions/answers here.  There can be lots of bad content, but as long as we create good content and promote it using existing mechanics, it will push the bad content out of the way.

Comment: I think any kind of moderation attracts people who like to power-trip and enforce rules for their own sake (usually thinking they have some moral imperative to do so, rather than actually seeing themselves as power-trippers). During the several years I've been using SO, I've seen the degree of closing and deletion, and the "deletion culture", steadily growing, and I think a community like this really needs to do something to counteract that. Like with most kinds of power, those most fit to wield it are those who don't want to, not those who jump at the chance to do so.

Comment: @necromancer, the amount of chaff one needs to go through to find the wheat when one is looking for good questions to answer has grown ridiculous. I used to be able to sign into SO and find an interesting question I could answer somewhere within the first page (of items having a tag in an area where I have some subject matter expertise) almost without fail. Over the years, that's become downright rare.

Search might make it easier for folks who are looking for good answers, but it doesn't help people looking for good questions in need of an answer.

Comment: @necromancer I wasn't saying anything but.  No disagreement here.  But at least on meta I could fight for my answer instead of just seeing "CLOSED."

Comment: @CharlesDuffy seems like a rather trivial problem to solve: search questions by number of upvotes? and perhaps more criteria: questions with N upvotes without an answer having M upvotes, or without an answer, etc. Why not push for this feature in SO rather than doubling down on closing?

Comment: @jalf: *“do you have a problem with the term?”* Yes. *“It's not the first time it crops up, and it probably won't be the last.”* You got me. I guess I can’t be annoyed about it, then. *“If you find this hard to swallow, do ask some of the more senior moderators about the last big close/delete war.”* I was there. Also: *“And maybe try, just try to pretend to keep your comments sounding respectful, or at least, non-dismissive, when you've got that friggin' diamond next to your name.”* Did you even read your last condescending sentence while you were writing this

Comment: @jalf: So, to sum up: **I am allowed to express exasperation at the fact that this is being brought up again.** I have a similar exasperation for the type of comment you just made. It’s incredibly rude, and hardly worthy of a response. But what the hey, I have a friggin’ diamond next to my name. Also, wow, both of your comments here are condescending. Please don’t talk to other real people like that.

Comment: @false for a moderator you crossed a rather low threshold to express your exasperation. actually, exasperation is the wrong word: you took the opportunity to express contempt and you were rather quick to it, and you did it solely to express contempt rather than as a side-effect of making some other point. i let it pass as did most members but it is really thin-skinned of you to protest so strongly when you get a taste of your own medicine. actually calling it your own medicine is unfair to @ jaif because at least he was making a point.

Comment: @false and just to be clear, the reason moderators should have a high threshold is because otherwise it significantly reduces the faith that the community needs to have in the people in charge.

Comment: @necromancer: I’m glad to be talking to the one who speaks for most members. Anyways, the point I am making is this: I think the phrase “deletion culture” is silly. Nothing more. You are making a big deal out of it. Of course, you’re also entitled to your opinion, so I’ll leave this here. But please stop telling me what I’m allowed to think.

Comment: @false: "Deletion culture" is a concept I took from a casual familiarity with a similar phenomenon on Wikipedia, though I'm not aware of the same phrase being used there. I use it to refer to the culture that places a value on the removal of content deemed harmful not in and of itself but by virtue of how it allegedly devalues the resource it's a part of by bringing down the average quality of content or similar. And I definitely see that culture on meta SO.

Comment: *why is meta so full of people like that when the rest of the community chugs along fine?* Simple, they see something that others do not yet understand. That is not a problem. I am happy that the "rest of community" is fine like this, but their way is simply creating the next Yahoo Answers. Quality is being overtaken by quantity. I understand that some people enjoy collecting their easy rep points every day, I was one of them, and they do not want that to stop. They masquerade it as "helping people". You are not helping this way, sorry.

Comment: Amen brother. Over-broad closing has made StackOverflow much less useful to me, as a former prolific answerer. It seems a lot of the closers enjoy carrying the big stick of authority more than they enjoy helping, learning, or teaching.

Answer (score 37):

In general, I agree that deleting potentially useful content is bad and should be avoided. The last time we had the big "deletion" debate, I came down strongly on the side of preservation. My side won, kinda—we got the [historical lock feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) implemented, which at least saved some of the old, albeit useful, no-longer-on-topic material from outright burnination.

Anyway, my point in leading with all of this is not to toot my own horn, but to lend credibility to the fact that **I disagree with you here**.

You don't point to any examples, and I don't know what you have seen in the Community Bulletin, but I can't recall any questions on Meta lately concerning the deletion of content that is even *remotely borderline*. The stuff that we discuss deleting, advocate deleting, and (generally) actually delete is stuff that *should never have been on the site in the first place*. It is just absolute garbage, wasting the time of anyone who ever has to cross across it. Time that they will never get back. That's the whole point of deletion, to minimize the amount of time others have to waste wading through the garbage.

You are an active participant on the site (or, at least, I've read many of your answers and found lots of them to be helpful), so surely you've noticed that there has been *a lot* of garbage getting posted recently. The things I've read on Meta recently from other high-rep users have confirmed what I've long feared I suffered alone: the volume of noise on Stack Overflow has gotten so high that it has made it difficult for me to find halfway-decent questions to answer and zapped my will to participate. I would be extremely surprised if your experience was substantially different.

We aren't talking about deleting stuff that *might* help someone in the future. We're talking about deleting stuff that is just making the site suck.

To quote myself:

> I see *absolutely* no point in keeping garbage around, but I think we should do *everything within our power* to keep potentially useful information alive and accessible on the Internet. I realize that this is incredibly subjective, but I think, like pornography, most people know it when they see it.
>   […] And in the edge cases, we should err on the side of preservation, rather than obliteration.

If I thought there was some kind of out-of-control deletion going on, I'd surely be throwing a fit about it.

It is possible that I've missed it. If you have examples to which you can point, I'm happy to reconsider.

Comment: 1. examples: plenty of questions are closed as duplicates that are not duplicates ([pick a tag where you are competent and see for yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-closereason=duplicate) (the error rate might be as high as 10% (very high))) 2. Number of "noise" questions might be higher but there are still [many questions to answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254592/4279) 3. repwhore-shaming is out-of-hand. [Q/A site shouldn't discourage volunteers from providing good answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254549/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You linked me to a *review* page, not a list of closed questions. I *do* regularly read questions in tags I'm competent in, and I hardly *ever* see questions that have been incorrectly closed as duplicates. Rather, I see lots of duplicate questions that *should* be closed; I vote to close them. Yes, occasionally people make mistakes in voting to close a question. That's why we have a review queue. If others disagree with their opinion, it is rejected, no harm done. Close votes also age away after some time if they are unconfirmed.

Comment: 2) I disagree. Of course, I've seen the Meta question you linked. I already do most of those things people talked about. I've tried them all at some time. I just don't have hours to spend pouring through lists of questions, filtering through all of the crap. I like to answer a question here and there while my code is compiling or tests are running. Instead, I spend all of my time moderating the crap, not posting answers. It is frustrating. Note that I didn't say there are *no* good questions, I said the volume of crap had been turned up to 11.

Comment: 3) Repwhoring is out of hand. It is the central problem that promotes people asking bad questions in the first place: they keep getting answers. Of course, my personal opinion aligns nearly 100% with [Shog's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254562/366904). But you need to apply some context here. The goal of Stack Overflow is not to earn reputation, it were, we'd give out simple participation points. A Q&A site isn't discouraging volunteers from proving *good* answers, we're trying to discourage people from giving *bad* answers to *bad* questions.

Comment: Just a FYI, I [reviewed](http://stackoverflow.com/users/302677/rachel?tab=activity&sort=reviews) all the duplicate votes in the WPF tag when I got my [shiny new superpowers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254589/302677), and roughly 80% were not duplicates. This made me feel really demoralized at the integrity of many of our close-happy users.

Comment: @Rachel: Just pulling one of your reviews at random, you voted Leave Open on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924556/force-window-to-blink-when-a-particular-event-occurs-in-c-sharp-wpf, but it is a duplicate of the one linked in the comments.  Both were answered with `FlashWindowEx` p/invoke code.  (Your comment that the other doesn't show how to flash the entire window is wrong, the only valid point is that the earlier question didn't mention flashing the whole window as a requirement.  But both wanted and got the same thing.)

Comment: @BenVoigt The questions are asking two separate things (how to make a full sized application window "flash", and how to make a window "flash" in the taskbar. In addition, I thought the answer of the one that had the close vote was far superior to the one that was being left open, so should not be closed.

Comment: @Rachel: I did read your comment.  And I just told you your comment was factually incorrect.  The accepted answer for the earlier question does make the regular-sized window blink (Well, its title bar, which is apparently the behavior desired.  Because the exact same solution got accepted, except that one used `FLASHW_ALL | FLASHW_TIMER` and the other `FLASHW_ALL | FLASHW_TIMERNOFG`)

Comment: I do agree that the answer on the newer question, with code directly in the post, is superior.  Should it be closed the other way?

Comment: There is definitely out-of-control deletion going on.  The deletists keep removing old, very popular questions, just see the latest on the [SO list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256639/13295).

Comment: @BenVoigt Because the two questions ask for different things, and will be found by different sets of users searching for a solution to different problems, no I think these two should be closed as duplicates to each other. Definitely link them, but don't close them as duplicates because they aren't duplicates.

Comment: You have just *described what a duplicate is for*. Questions that *appear* to ask for two different things, and will be found by different sets of users searching for solutions, but actually have the same answer.

Comment: @CodyGray I see you also closed the WPF question as a duplicate to a WinForms question. I've reopened it because there is some WPF-specific solutions posted to that question, and I do not think it should be closed as a dup to an older Winforms question.

Comment: **They have exactly the same answer**. That is what a duplicate is. WPF people won't think to look at the WinForms questions for their answer, but people who understand the problem and know how to solve it already know this. They're the people we allow to close as duplicates, for precisely this reason. You could literally copy and paste an answer from any one of those questions to any of the others, and it would be the correct answer. That's a duplicate.

Comment: @CodyGray No, only one answer is a duplicate. There are other answers to the WPF question which do not adequately answer the Winforms question (which specifically asks for a Win API call). And people search for the solution to *their problem*, they don't know to search for *the* solution because they don't know what the solution is. That is why I feel that different questions with the same answer and not duplicates.

Comment: Obviously you are missing the fact that there *is* no other way to do this than making a Win API call. Any code that is written, regardless of the language and the UI framework, is going to make such a call. Yes, that's the part the person asking the question is not expected to know. That's why closing a question as a duplicate is not a punishment. But it is something that experts know, that's why we have the ability to mark duplicates now. All of the answers to all of the questions adequately answer any of the other questions. If not, it's because they're link-only and don't answer anything.

Comment: @CodyGray And that is one reason why we have this split between meta "close warriors" and regular users :) People have different definitions of what is considered a duplicate or not. Those on meta often share a stricter view of duplicates, while those who frequently use the site often have a looser view of duplicates.

Comment: @Rachel and Cody, I see some dangerous statement in this comments but so maybe some clarification is needed: duplicates are for questions that ask fundamentally the **same problem** just with different wording. That two questions has similar answers can be an indicator but not the sole variable to close as duplicates.

Comment: @Rachel: Since you linked to it above, I took a quick look at your review log. Meaning no disrespect, I'm kind of curious about why you reviewed [this item](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4905040) as "Leave Open", even though the two questions are *exactly* word-for-word identical, except for their title and minor changes in code formatting and punctuation (which were edited in by another user)?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen That's fine :) Both questions are asked by the same user. The first asked how to navigate using gestures, to which one answer is to use Pivot, and the second is asking how to increase the PivotIndex to navigate, which is a separate question based on the answer to the first one.

Comment: @Rachel: Um, did you read the actual text of the questions? They're *literally the same question*, copy-pasted. The only difference is the title (which probably should've been a comment on the older question's answer).

Comment: @Braiam That's exactly what the questions are. They ask fundamentally the same thing. It is the same problem with different wording. And we aren't talking about *similar* answers, we are talking about *exactly* the same answer, with no other potential possibilities. There is a reason that we trust tag experts to close questions, because they know the problem domain and what is/is not a duplicate better than anyone. I looked at your profile, and I don't see any indication that you're an expert on Windows programming. By the same token, you won't see me closing any Javascript questions as dupes.

Comment: @CodyGray: As someone trying to actually help people with questions and get help myself, and who's built a load of rep doing that, I really don't care about "rep whoring". If gaming rep by answering poor-quality questions lets someone get more rep than they "should" have (i.e. ability to do things that are harmful, which they end up doing) there should be a more intelligent way to deal with that than cutting off their supply of easy-to-answer questions and making the site more hostile to users who want to ask and answer questions.

Comment: I've gotten bitten by unwarranted closure enough times, while in the middle of writing a detailed answer to a question that's actually legitimate and interesting, that I've resorted to throwing up a quick-and-dirty answer first when I see a question worth answering that looks like the close-warriors will jump on it, then going back and editing in the long answer I actually wanted to write once I don't have to worry that closure will result in my answer being thrown away.

Answer (score 21):

> Why is meta full of close-warriors?

Because meta is largely populated with users who have gotten tired of just using the main site, and now want to influence how it runs.

They want to clean things up, put them in their place, and organize the massive jumble of content we call Q&A.

Not a bad goal, however I have to agree with you that it leads to a culture that seems very pro-closure and pro-deletion to regular users.

Comment: From Stack Overflow Help: *With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.* vs your *They want to clean things up, put them in their place, and organize the massive jumble of content we call Q&A.* Isn't that the whole point?

Comment: @kapa: That's not the *whole* point of the site, no. *Part* of the point of the site IMO is to continue answering new questions as they arise. Especially the good questions :-) I've previously argued that SO probably has enough jumble that actually we could stop getting new questions entirely for a considerable period and still have plenty of organization to do, working towards the site's main goal. But that would rather miss the point, I feel. If Rachel has identified a true reason why meta is largely concerned with decluttering, great! You don't need to be on meta just to answer questions.

Comment: Part of the problem is that "de-cluttering" in the sense or *removal* is a pre-Internet mindset which is generally a loosing proposition in this day and age.  As content can be created faster than it can be suppressed, it's going to be necessary to stop worrying about what is out there overall, and instead focus on better tools and tagging **for directing viewers to what is personally useful or interesting**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton deleting is easier than fixing.. and sometimes I just feel like I should build ground up to fix some questions, so they just doesn't worth my time to fix.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: so you're saying that noise to signal ratio should merely introduce an O(log N) term to your search functions? ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Oh, those good questions. People still tell legends about them, from the times they still existed ;). OK, serious. So you say another goal is to continue answering questions. But if we reach the goal *detailed answers to every question about programming*, what do we continue answering? :)

Comment: @kapa: I'm pretty certain that new questions about programming will be invented as soon as we're finished, so "all" we need to do is: (1) answer all the good questions that exist in the universe; (2) delete everything else from the site; (3) continue answering all new good questions as they're invented. Not necessarily in that order. Mission accomplished.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I like what you're saying, but then SO is doing a really terrible job :).

Comment: @kapa: SO is doing an excellent job. Google search results for practical programming problems I face frequently come up with excellent answers on SO. What "close-warriors" are primarily concerned with, as far as I can tell, is that the "recent questions" lists and the edit queues are mostly garbage. The public don't see those, it's a second order problem *mostly* to do with keeping expert answerers enthused about the site. That's where SO is starting to ease off the pace, and what quite a few people (whether they're close-warriors or not) feel is an imminent crisis.

Comment: @SteveJessop Of course. But if we do not change things, we will still answer questions about the difference between x++ and ++x or maybe returning AJAX responses from a function instead of focusing on those new problems.

Comment: @Braiam - what is useful is extremely subjective - the problem with anyone who tries to enforce a one-size-fits-all version of utility is that they'll end up in an endless war with the many who see differently.  Ultimately the only long-term-workable path is going to be one which can **accommodate differences in needs** - and that's reader filtering, not post deletion (or the even more pointless "closing" - which only serves to prevent others from answring).

Comment: @ChrisStratton Some say that would help. I say that is only creating a ghetto of low-quality questions. Questions that should simply never be allowed to enter this site.

Comment: @kapa - again, this is the problem of difference in needs.  What meets one person's idea of a low quality, uninteresting question can have precisely the answer needed for another person's current issue, or contain within it something that those with *specifically relevant experience* recognize to be a unique and intriguing technical problem.  Fundamentally, you simply cannot have a site this big run smoothly while still trying to enforce a one-size-fits-all mentality.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Nope. A low quality question is a low quality question. In 95% of cases it is very easy to determine. We can argue about the remaing 5%, I might even agree with you, but first, we need that 95% out. We can worry about everything else later. When you are drowning, you are naturally not worrying about your haircut, because you have more important problems :).

Comment: No, it is precisely reversing the improper closure of that 5-10% (or more like 40% in some tags) of interesting questions which consumes the most time.  Fundamentally, an "answer ban" is not a constructive status for a question.  If there's a real concern about users answering "bad" questions just to earn reputation (rather than to be genuinely helpful) then let's have a "reputation ban" status where a question cannot earn its asker or answerer any reputation, uninterested parties can tick a box not to see them, but answers are still permitted from those who deem the question worthwhile.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I would be perfectly happy with a reputation ban for answers on closed questions if we could get rid of the answer ban. If I'm trying to answer a question it's not about reputation. I have more than I could ever use and I just want to provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's an inevitable progression as a community-led site matures and wants to be more legitimate. Wikipedia and TV Tropes have gone through similar progressions where the site contains enough professional-grade material that people want it to become more legitimate by getting rid of the more embarrassing bits.

That said, this site seems fairly good at not going overboard on such a subject.

Comment: The comparison to Wikipedia is quite apt, I think. I hadn't thought about that before. I recall Wikipedia had to establish very strict standards for ["notability"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Notability) during its late formative years. Lots of "popular" articles were deleted because they did not meet those standards. This is operating for Stack Overflow as well. In order to meet the high quality standards we set for ourselves, we have to set the boundaries somewhere.

Comment: I think Wikipedia article deletion is a great analogy for what's happening on SO with the eagerness to close and delete, but Wikipedia is really nothing like SO, and I think the unreasonable extension of this analogy might actually be a big part of the cause of the problem -- people come here and get the idea that they're supposed to treat it like Wikipedia, and that the primary goal is to provide a carefully-curated resource of programming knowledge rather than actively answer people's questions.

Comment: @R.. I've always understood SO as a carefully curated resource of programming knowledge and thats the reason I'm here. If this were "just" a place were people actively answer other peoples questions this would be another programming forum and I've left so many of those - exactly because of this.

Comment: Part of the problem, in my mind, is that a little power goes a long way, especially if that's your only power.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer: I completely fail to understand the reasoning behind that mindset. Who does it benefit? While I occasionally find useful information for a problem I solve in past questions, the vast majority of the benefit I've gotten out of SO, and contributed for others to get, is in the *active process* of asking and answering questions, not treating past questions as some sort of archive of knowledge.

Comment: As for your other point, moderating is definitely not what distinguishes SO from "another programming forum". The Q&A format, the lack of fake content in the form of tricking google that there's an answer to a question when there's really not, and the ability of anyone to participate without registration or paywalls is what distinguishes SO and makes it a^H the only useful resource of its kind.

Comment: @R.. Then we obviously use SO very different. Next to all questions I had were already asked and answered in a way that helped me. That isn't so surprising if we take into account that you are active in completely different tags/topics than I am. - Most likely the experience is totally different to you as the users that come and ask questions in your realm are different to mine. - And at least compared to the Java Forums, were I was before I came to SO, the moderation and working search function is what distinguishes SO from them.